# Java field descriptor for Object[][]

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface, native-methods

Whats field descriptor for an Object[][] within a method descriptor? Say there exists a class foo.bar.Class and a method takes a Class[][], according to

http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jvms/second_edition/html/ClassFile.doc.html#14152

or the JNI specification my understanding is that it should be

```
[[Lfoo/bar/Class;
```

but that is evaluated to an array of "[foo.bar.Class" which of course triggers a `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError`.

Should the "inner" array probably be considered a java.lang.Object, resulting in

```
[Ljava/lang/Object;
```

?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are doing something wrong I guess. This works for me:

```
package ro.redeul.test;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchMethodException {
        System.out.println("x: " + Test.class.getMethod("method").getReturnType().toString());
    }

    public Test[][] method() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

it prints `x: class [[Lro.redeul.test.Test;`

Can you provide more context ?

Comment: i was indeed overlooking a typo :( missing the ';' at one place at the end of a descriptor string. issue resolved :)

Comment: i also figured in the meanwhile that an easy way to verify descriptor strings is "javap -c"